# Consulta con valores separados por comas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas que deben ir relacionadas. En la primera llamada "candidate" se almacena los datos de candidatos a "presidente" y "vocal".

En la segunda llamada "vote" se almacenan los votos de los usuarios. En esa tabla se almacena el “user_id” de usuario que vota (para permitirle que solo vote 1 sola vez) y luego dos campos que son “presidente” y “vocal”. El valor "0" corresponde a voto en blanco.

En el campo presidente se almacena el `id` del candidato con cargo presidente y en vocal el `id` del candidato con cargo vocal. Se puede votar a un máximo de 2 vocales, por lo que en el campo vocal he almacenado los ids separados con “,” por ejemplo el usuario 1 vota a los vocales 5,6.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema ahora es sacar una consulta que cuente tanto los votos del presidente como de los vocales.

Utilizando esta consulta logro contar los votos para el presidente:

```
SELECT count(*) as presidente FROM candidate, vote WHERE candidate.id = vote.president
```

He intentado hacer esto para contar los votos de los vocales y me sale un error:

```
SELECT * FROM candidate, vote WHERE vote.vocal in (select id from vote where candidate.cargo=vote.vocal)
```

Me aparece un Warning con los valores del campo vocal. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo no te recomiendo para nada que almacenes dos valores en el mismo campo separados por comas, ¿por qué simplemente no creas otro campo llamado vocal2?
Eso te simplificaría muchos las cosas e incluso podrías establecer relaciones foráneas para asegurar la integridad de tu información.

Pero si lo que quieres es hacer lo que me comentas lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma.

```
SELECT count(*) as votos_del_vocal, '6' as id_del_vocal FROM vote WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(vote.vocal, ',',1) = '6' or SUBSTRING_INDEX(vote.vocal, ',',-1) = '6'
```

Con esto cuentas los votos que obtuvo el vocal 6, si quieres contar los del 7 reemplaza todos los 6 por 7, no se te olvide ponerlo entre comillas ya que son string.

Comment: Buena solución. Es cierto lo que dices, el problema que encuentro es que en las votaciones se puede votar máximo 2 vocales y 1 presidente. Tengo un form con un input para presidente y con un checkbox para vocales (limitado a dos selecciones). Si pudiera hacerlo de otra manera lo guardaría como vocal2, pero no sé como hacerlo...

Comment: Que lenguaje usas como backend?

Comment: Utilizo php y html. Quizás debería ser otra pregunta o si me puedes ayudar por aquí, lo agradezco

Comment: Estaría bien, para que puedas poner más información

Comment: La pregunta está aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369559/guardar-varios-checkbox-en-diferentes-campos-mysql