# Guardar varios checkbox en diferentes campos mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente formulario para elegir a un presidente y a dos vocales:

```
<form method="post" action="">

</h2>Presidente</h2>

    <!-- Cargo los datos del presidente con un while por eso el valor del input es el $id -->
    <input type="radio" name="president" id="president" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <span class="input-group-text">Presidente 1</span>

    <input type="radio" name="president" id="president" value="0">
    <span class="input-group-text">Voto en blanco</span>
        
</h2>Vocal</h2>
<p>Votar máximo 2 o en blanco</p>

    <!-- Cargo los datos de los vocales con un while por eso el valor del input es el $id -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="vocal[]" id="vocal" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <span class="input-group-text">Vocal 1</span>

    <input type="checkbox" name="vocal[]" id="vocal" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <span class="input-group-text">Vocal 2</span>
                    
    <input type="checkbox" name="vocal[]" id="vocal" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <span class="input-group-text">Vocal 3</span>

    <input type="checkbox" name="vocal[]" id="vocal" value="0">
    <span class="input-group-text">Voto en blanco</span>
                        
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Send vote</button>

</form>
```

El valor de voto en blanco = 0.

Ahora lo que hago es limitar que se puedan solo marcar 2 checkboxes como máximo.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        var cantidadMaxima=2;
    // Evento que se ejecuta al soltar una tecla en el input
    $("#cantidad").keydown(function(){
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);
        $("#seleccionados").html("0");
    });
    // Evento que se ejecuta al pulsar en un checkbox
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
        // Cogemos el elemento actual
        var elemento=this;
        var contador=0;
        // Recorremos todos los checkbox para contar los que estan seleccionados
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
                contador++;
        });
        // Comprovamos si supera la cantidad máxima indicada
        if(contador>cantidadMaxima)
        {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');    
            // Desmarcamos el ultimo elemento
            $(elemento).prop('checked', false);
            contador--;
        }
        $("#seleccionados").html(contador);
    });
});
</script>
```

Y por último quiero guardar esos valores en una tabla donde almacena el id del usuario que vota,  y su voto por el presidente y por cada vocal. Lo que no sé es como hacer que los votos de los vocales vayan a dos campos diferentes de la tabla llamados "vocal1" "vocal2", y si pudiera poner otro campo que fuera "voto en blanco" sería genial.

Como no se hacerlo hice un array y almacené los checkboxes en un mismo campo separado por coma ",".

```
// Insert record
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        
    $president=$_POST['president'];
    $checkBox = implode(',', $_POST['vocal']); 

    if(!empty($president)){
  
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO vote (user_id, president, vocal) VALUES('" . $user_id . "', '" . $president . "', '" . $checkBox . "')");
    }
  }
```

Si hay una manera más eficiente de hacerlo para luego contar los votos me gustaría saber cómo.

Comment: Y normalizar la tabla seria algo ideal.. una tabla de votos donde diga quien voto, el cargo y a quien voto..

Comment: Yo lo que estoy guardando en esa tabla votos es quién votó (user_id) y almaceno en el campo presidente el id del cantidato y en el campo vocal los ids de los vocales que ese usuario votó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una disculpa no había tenido tiempo de conectarme, ay tienes un ejemplo de como podrías insertar en dos campos diferentes.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" name="form" id="form">

</h2>Presidente</h2>

    <!-- Cargo los datos del presidente con un while por eso el valor del input es el $id -->
    <input type="radio" name="president" id="president" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <span class="input-group-text">Presidente 1</span>

    <input type="radio" name="president" id="president" value="0">
    <span class="input-group-text">Voto en blanco</span>
        
</h2>Vocal</h2>
<p>Votar máximo 2 o en blanco</p>

    <!-- Cargo los datos de los vocales con un while por eso el valor del input es el $id -->
    <div id="form1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vocal1" id="vocal1" value="vocal1" onchange="twoSelectionValidation('form1', this)">
    <span class="input-group-text">Vocal 1</span>

    <input type="checkbox" name="vocal2" id="vocal2" value="vocal2" onchange="twoSelectionValidation('form1', this)">
    <span class="input-group-text">Vocal 2</span>
                    
    <input type="checkbox" name="vocal3" id="vocal3" value="vocal3" onchange="twoSelectionValidation('form1', this)">
    <span class="input-group-text">Vocal 3</span>

    <input type="checkbox" name="votoblanco" id="votoblanco" value="0" onchange="twoSelectionValidation('form1', this)">
    <span class="input-group-text">Voto en blanco</span>
    </div>
                        
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Send vote</button>

</form>

<script>
    function twoSelectionValidation(form, inputcb) {
        limit=2;
        count=0;
        if (inputcb.checked) {
            for (i=0; cb=document.getElementById(form).children[i]; i++)
            if (cb.checked) count++;
        if (count>limit)
        inputcb.checked=false;
        }
        }  



</script>
    
</body>
</html>
<?php
// Insert record
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user_id  = 'user';

    $president = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['president'])){
        $president = $_POST['president'];
    }

    $vocalesArray = array(0,0,0,0);
    $v1 = 0;
    $v2 = 0;
    $v3 = 0;
    $v4 = 0;

    if(isset($_POST['vocal1'])){
        $v1=$_POST['vocal1'];
        $vocalesArray[0] = $v1;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['vocal2'])){
        $v2=$_POST['vocal2'];
        if($vocalesArray[0]=='0'){
            $vocalesArray[0] = $v2;
        }else if($vocalesArray[1]=='0'){
            $vocalesArray[1] = $v2;
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['vocal3'])){
        $v3=$_POST['vocal3'];
        if($vocalesArray[0]=='0'){
            $vocalesArray[0] = $v3;
        }else if($vocalesArray[1]=='0'){
            $vocalesArray[1] = $v3;
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['votoblanco'])){
        $v4=$_POST['votoblanco'];
        if($vocalesArray[0]=='0'){
            $vocalesArray[0] = $v4;
        }else if($vocalesArray[1]=='0'){
            $vocalesArray[1] = $v4;
        }
    }








    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO vote (user_id, president, vocal1, vocal2) VALUES('" . $user_id . "', '" . $president . "', '" . $vocalesArray[0] . "', '" .$vocalesArray[1]."')");
}
  ?>
```

Lo único que hice es que agregue un div entonces de ahí tomo los hijos y valido que no estén chequeados más de dos, por cierto elimine el jquery ya que se puede hacer con funciones muy sencillas de JS, lo demás lo valido desde el back end con PHP y lo hago de una forma muy practica en la cual lo primero que hace el código es validad que las variables lleguen y aquí esta lo practico, las variables que no llegan sencillamente se toma como ceros es decir votos nulos, si solo marca a un vocal o si o escoge presidente se toma como nulo, luego de que se validan las variables  para que no causen problemas, al igual que tú las meto en un array y luego lo organizo para posteriormente guardarlo en la bd solo tomando como referencia las dos primeas posiciones del array.
Por cierto, debes agregar un nuevo campo en tu bd que sería el de vocale2 y editar el nombre del otro que ya tenías por vocales1.
No olvides cambiar el nombre de las variables que les puse temporalmente los candidatos por los valores que es tenías asignados.
Como lo mencionan en la parte de arriba también te recomiendo que normalices la bd, pero si te decides por hacerlo con estos ejemplos te podrás guiar un poco sobre lo que querías hacer.
Espero que te sirva de algo, si tienes alguna duda necesitas algo cométalo, saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, va perfectamente, y lo mejor de todo es que ahora lo entiendo.

Answer (score 4):

Tu tabla de votos tiene que ser normalizada para permitirte mas flexibilidad y tambien para facilitarte luego los conteos.

Lo que podrias hacer es una tabla de votos con los siguientes campos:

> Id_usuario: el usuario que vota
> Id_cargo: el cargo que esta votando
> Id_persona: la persona por la cual se vota.

Vas a necesitar una tabla de cargos (que contendra por ejemplo presidente, vocal, suplente, etc)

Y otra tabla con las personas que se postulan a cada cargo. Inclusive, esa tabla podra tener a la persona Voto en blanco (que lo definiras como queres) y hasta si tuvieras votos invalidos, tambien lo podrias poner como persona. De esa forma, contar cada tipo de voto es solo hacer un sum...

Comment: Entiendo, pero ¿cómo almacenas los valores de los checkboxes en diferentes campos?

Comment: @Jok igual que como haces en tu array, o ahi tampoco lo habias arreglado al problema?

Comment: Quizás no lo estoy entendiendo o no lo estoy explicando bien ¿No hay ningún problema en almacenar datos así? "6,7". Ahora mismo almaceno así los votos de los vocales, en un solo campo y separados por comas... mi intención es guardarlos en dos campos diferentes llamados "vocal 1" y "vocal 2". Creo que mi duda está en la consulta que debería hacer para llevar el `value` de los checkbox a campos diferentes.

Comment: En lugar de guardarlos en dos campos, o de guardarlos separados por coma, los guardas en esta tabla 1 por fila..

Comment: de esta forma, cuando haya 3 vocales, o un secretario, no tenes que modificar todo tu sistema. @Jok

Comment: Si, definitivamente es necesario normalizarla. Independientemente de ello, mi pregunta iba relacionada al guardado de varios checkbox, ya que hay otros proyectos que tengo que se necesita igualmente para bases de datos normalizadas. Muchas gracias